# Excel UDF returns a huge number

Tags: user-defined-functions, excel-addins, excel-dna

Excel AddIn using Excel DNA, VS2008, C#, 
MyUDF(param1, parm2) 
when I type in "=MyUDF" and hit enter, Excel displays a huge number like 970063926
and my c# code for MyUDF is not run

Anyone know what is this huge number?

thanks

Comment: Are you not passing in the parameters the function needs? It won't run if you aren't passing in 2 parameters and without seeing your code, that's all I can say :(

Comment: No, I did not pass any parameters. So what is the huge number and how to avoid it or display more meaningful message in this case? thanks

Comment: I wish I could tell you. I tried all sorts of typing mistakes on my own c# add-in UDFs and in all cases, I get a #NAME error if I forget to pass paramaters. Sorry I couldn't be of any help, hopefully someone else will see the thread/comments and answer it for you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bit of weird behaviour of Excel. The number being returned is an internal identifier for the UDF function, and by entering the function name without any brackets, you're causing it to be treated like a named range not a function. If you want to call the function with no arguments, use:

```
=MyUDF()
```

...if you type `=MyUDF` then you're asking Excel to dereference the function name, in the same way that it would dereference `=A1` to the value in cell `A1` or `=MyNamedRange` to whatever that named range referred to.

I don't think there's any practical use for the behaviour you've observed, but it certainly isn't going anywhere near your code to get this value that is being returned, so don't worry you haven't done anything wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?
If no parameter is specified, I would like the =MyUDF to return error instead a number.